# How to disable installed jenkins as windows service and run the same jenkins in cmd?

Tags: jenkins, windows-services

I want to init the Jenkins not by service, but by my self(As windows user) in cmd!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to your services and stop Jenkins service. To see all your services run `services.msc`, from there find Jenkins service and disable\stop it.
2. Open up "cmd" as administrator.
3. In cmd navigate to where you installed Jenkins, by default it should be in `C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins`.
4. Run the command:

   ```
   java -jar jenkins.war
   ```

This should start Jenkins for you in cmd now use your address and port which you already defined for installed Jenkins.

In case you want to have fresh start. Download latest jenkins.war file or copy your .war file to another directory and run the `java -jar` command.

If you want to go back to your installed Jenkins close the cmd which is running Jenkins and start the service back up.

Comment: I've tried this mode, but the Jenkins didn't load the previous configuration, but started a new instance! How can i load the jenkins previous configuration?

Comment: did you start the jenkins.war at C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins? You could check the Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Home Directory path. Make sure it's same in both the service and war instance you started.

Comment: A few tips to get this working on Windows:
* Make sure you set your JENKINS_HOME environment variable (as mentioned by others)
* Use the version of java embedded with Jenkins.  In other words: Tip: In order to get this working on Windows, I had to use the java version embedded with my Jenkins installation.  In other words:  "jre\bin\java.exe -jar jenkins.war"

Answer (score 3):

Besides to steps provided by Ahmed, it was necessary for me to set the JENKINS_HOME environmental variable to force the Jenkins to use its old configuration. By default it tried to use C:\Users\%USERNAME%.jenkins\  directory.

Comment: You should add your findings to Ahmeds answer  by editing it or if you cannot edit add Ahmeds steps also to your answer to make it complete.

Comment: I was unable to comment Ahmed's answer because of "You must have 50 reputation..."